# Screen blank ('no signal') after choice "try Ubuntu"

Tags: boot, 12.10, live-cd

I made a live CD and booted it up and chose to "try Ubuntu".

Some stuff happened and now my screen is just blank and my monitor says `no signal`.

Whats happening? Is it installing or what? Its been like this for about 10-15 minutes.

Comment: What does "some stiff happened" mean? If it is a typo for "stuff", could you explain a little bit more what happened?

Answer (score 1):

Video mode setting may be failing during the boot process for some reason. You may need to try setting the 'nomodeset' option at boot.

Look here for a guide to change kernel boot options on the Live media: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_the_CD_Boot_Option_Configuration_Line